# async testing angular controller and services with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I am just getting started with `Angular`. I really like the design and it's actually very nice to test. One thing I can't get to seem working is testing `asynchronous services` and their hookups to `controllers`.
Just to make sure I did understand Angulars `$q` correctly, if my **service** looks something like this;

```js
 this.AsyncTask = function (params) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        doAsyncStuff(params, function () {
            if (iAmReady) {
                deferred.resolve("Success");
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

This essentially does the following as I see it. Do async stuff and return a promise (that it is working on the async stuff). When the event is processed at some point, "notify" the promise that the async task is done and return back some values to it. Now in my **controller** I would do.

```js
MyService.AsyncTask(params).then(function (value) {
    if (value) {
        $scope.success = value;
    }
});
```

Here the controller instructs the service to do the AsyncTask (with some params) and the `.then` tells when the service is done with the async task, and the controller can do some logic based on that result.
**So far so good**, this actually in production does exactly what I want, however I am not able to unit test it with `jasmine`.
I tried a lot of possible solutions out there (including [Angulars official example on that](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) as well as jasmines `done` functionality) but I cant seem to make it work and these are the **problems I'm facing**:

1. In my **service**, either the `expect` **never gets called** (or be more precisely gets called too early since the results are correct when debugging)
2. Or when I use jasmines `done` (for example inside a `.then`) in my mocked up controller, it always times out and never gets called.
3. When using the way described in Angular's unit test example, calling `$rootScope.$apply` doesn't do anything for me and problem 1 again.

So I would be really glad if you could give me some hints on how to generally approach this.

Comment: Could you please show your test so far?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your test code for each of your described problems, in general you can test async services like so:

```
describe('service', function() {
  // alter to match your module name
  beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));

  it('should test async calls', function (done) {
    //inject your services
    inject(function(MyService) {
      MyService.AsyncTask({/*your params*/})
        .then(function (result) {
          expect(result).toBeDefined();
          // add more tests
          done();
        }).catch(function (err) {
          // don't forget this. If something goes wrong, you wanna know 
          // why and don't run into a non-saying timeout error
          fail('Failure during AsyncTask: ' + err);
          done(); // important so that the runner knows the test is over
                  // even if it failed
        });
    });
  });
});
```

When you are running async tests with Jasmine 2.0, you need to call the `done` method after you are done with testing. If the default timeout is not sufficient for a test, you can define a timeout for an individual test:

```
it('should ...', function(done) { ... }, 10000); // timeout set to 10 sec
```

Some more thoughts on your issue: if the `doAsyncStuff` reaches out to a server, you might need to either mock it or define a proxy in the [karma config](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html). Watch the console in the browser where the tests are running to get more clues.